# How to connect Filezilla over ssh?

Tags: ssh, putty, filezilla

I am using putty for connecting to server and vi editor working with files. The way its work is, at first I use my username and password to login to server. Then I use the following command

sudo su - abc-app

and then

ssh 12.3.45.678

to login to server. So now my question is, is there any way I can do this using Filezilla??

Please help me guys

Comment: What exactly do you want to do once you log into the server?  Are you looking to do file transferee to you local machine?  Are you trying to admin the machine?  If the latter, you can't really do that with filezilla.

Comment: Actually I want to download files to local machine, edit files and then I want to upload again. Thats the thing I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

When you do that, its sftp, not ssh, you are just using an ssh channel to make the connection.

You need to actually install an SSH server if you want to connect for anything other than file transfers. [This article](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/install-SSH-Server-Windows-Server-2008.html) goes over various program for doing so. The article is centered around server 2008, but should be applicable to most modern versions of Windows.

Comment: sftp is just file transfer over ssh. They use the same protocol. If the server supports sftp then it will also support ssh, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), it can connect to a remote machine over SSH or SFTP. You can then browse the file system and edit files using a built-in or external editor.

Comment: Hi Nithin, thanks for your response, I will try tomorrow and let u know. Thanks